# How can I stop the repetition of a value that has been already been checked in a function?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
int [] firstArr = Utils.arrGen(len, min, max);
int [] secondArr = Utils.arrGen(len, min, max);
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
   int [] result = Utils.arrRepeatCheck(secondArr, firstArr[i]);
   if (result[1] != 0) {
      System.out.println("The number " + result[0] + " was found to be repetetive in the arrays " + result[1] + " times!");
   }
}
```

```
public static int [] arrRepeatCheck(int [] arr, int num) {
   int counter = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == num) {
         counter++;
      }
   }


int [] result = {num, counter};
return result;
```

(The function Utils.arrGen generates arrays with random values in them in a certain range, btw arrRepeartCheck is already in the utils class.)

I tried using an if statement to check if the number has been already tested, but it failed.

```
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 2 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 8 times!
The number 0 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 0 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 2 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 8 times!
The number 0 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 2 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 8 times!
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 2 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 8 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 0 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 0 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 2 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 8 times!
The number 1 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 12 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 0 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!
The number 3 was found to be repetetive in the arrays 15 times!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `but it failed.` Can you produce a [mcve] that illustrates this?  Something with a much smaller array please, we don't want to have to search huge arrays full of numbers.  What result are you looking for?

Comment: I am trying to make the program not repeat numbers that have been already tested.

Comment: Build a set of the numbers you have checked so far, if you've checked a number previously, skip it.

Comment: good idea, I will try storing them in an array and then checking the array has the used numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, by making an array that stores successful checks, I can simply check if the array has an already checked number, thus stopping the repetition.

```
int [] debug = new int [firstArr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < firstArr.length; i++) {
    result = Utils.arrRepeatCheck(secondArr, firstArr[i]);
    if ((result[1] != 0) & (Utils.arrRepeatCheck(debug, result[0])[1] < 1)) {
        System.out.println("The number " + result[0] + " was found to be repetetive in the arrays " + result[1] + " times!");
        debug[i] = result[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a set before checking its values.  This will remove all duplicates.

Try something like this:

```java
var mySet = IntStream.of(firstArr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
for (int i = 0; i < mySet.size(); i++) {
  int [] result = arrRepeatCheck(secondArr, (Integer) mySet.toArray()[i]);
  if (result[1] != 0) {
    System.out.println("The number " + result[0] + " was found to be repetetive in the arrays " + result[1] + " times!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response @skidwiz , but I have found quite a simple way to solve this: [link](https://pastebin.com/h1VN5ZqY) This checks numbers that have been already "used" using an array, thus solving the problem.

fyi: i dont know how to send a snippet of code in a comment

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to answer your own question with your solution.  This way other people can see it.